# How to keep data from input tag on the webpage even when I refresh or reload the page using Jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I am finding difficult on how to keep a data permanently on the webpage from an input tag  when I make a post request to my node.js server using Jquery even though I refresh or reload the page I want the data to remain on the webpage.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#task-btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let task = {
            description: $('#title').val(),
        };

        if(task.description === "" || task.description === null){
            return alert('Field cannot be empty!')
        }
        let table = `<tbody>
                        <tr class="table-data">
                            <td class="title"><p id="task">${task.description}</p></td>
                            <td class="image"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></td>
                            <td class="icon">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></li>
                                    <li class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>`;
                     $('.table').append(table);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/tasks',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(task),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Task Created Successfully!')
                console.log(data)
            },

            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code above is working properly, but how do I prevent the table variable from disappearing each time I reload or refresh the web page?